# Use of inventory_processed

Tags: magento-1.8

In the **Sales Quote related files** there is a FLAG called "`inventory_processed`" , but it is not available in `database` or anywhere else, actually what is the use of it ?

*Source Code File location :*

```
magento1.8\app\code\core\Mage\CatalogInventory\Model\Observer.php
```

Answer (score 0):

`$quote->setInventoryProcessed(true)` used to process `inventory` for the `quote`, so after setting this value Magento will not decrease the qty of product. I think this is usage of only magento `magic` method.

Comment: sorry that flag was not used for it